# Regex to match a email to contains at least one character

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match an email which:

- must contain at least one alphabet
- can contain digits
- can contain `_` and `.`.
- must be an email format (i.e., contains @something.something)

I have found this

`^((?=.*[a-zA-Z])\w+([\.-]?\w+)*)@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$`

but it is accepting `12345@gmail.com`, which is invalid according to my specs

Comment: `12345@gmail.com` is valid as per your specs.

Comment: then edit your question first constraint in specs should be "must contain at least one alphabet" I think @Kakashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your specs I've created the following Regex for you

```
^\w*[A-Za-z]+(?:([._]?\w+)*)\@[A-Za-z]\w*[-]?\w+\.[A-Za-z]{1,}?(\.?[A-Za-z]+)$
```

It should work for all your edge cases, and it also covers all the domain names including with `-` like `former-player` and also `.co.uk` and such

Comment: I've edited the Regex in the answer @Kakashi, please use the edited one. It should work. And please accept the answer if it works for you.